# Eclipse on Windows 7

Tags: eclipse, windows-7

Every time I open eclipse Galilio on Windows 7 64bit this message appear
and it won't work

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Faild to load the JNI shared library "C:\Program Files(x86)\java\jre6\client\jvm.dll"
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Help me please.

Comment: Does the dll exist? Can you run other Java programs?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the 64-bit distribution of Galileo, you need a 64bit distribution of JRE (not a 32bit installed in "`C:\Program Files(x86)`").

If not (you are using a 32bit) version, you can (as in [this thread](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&goto=542743&)),

> - Check your path variable,
> - make sure that if you type "`java -version`" at a command prompt you get the version you expect.
> - Or better yet, edit your **[eclipse.ini file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/1409590#1409590)** to specify a particular JVM location.
>     See http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini for examples.

Comment: The jre I used is from this page http://java.com/en/download/manual.jsp How can I know if my jre is 64-bit

Comment: The dll exist but I don't know if other java program work I'll check

Comment: @SultanSh: `java -version` should be enough

Comment: Thanx Vonc your are advice was the solution.
the only problem was I have to make a folder named JRE6 not JRE.

Comment: @SultanSh: interesting: that way, you follow the default path where it expect to find a JRE.

Answer (score 0):

Now check out what's below. This should help you fix your Eclipse issue with Java and Windows 7 64-bit.

Eclipse will not open when the exe is clicked on Windows 7 64-bit OS.

Eclipse Standard/SDK 
Version: Kepler Release 
Build ID: 2013614-0229

This is for the Firefox v22 64-bit browser 
OS: Windows OS 64-bit

1. Okay, you assume that Java is set properly on your Windows 64-bit PC and you've loaded Eclipse in a folder on your desktop. You've also created a separate folder called Eclipse Workspace which also resides on the desktop. Now you're ready to go and then in the Eclipse/Eclipse directory you click the Eclipse.exe and then you get this janky error message after the Eclipse window opens:

"Java was started but returned exit code=1" (with other related data)

or ------->

1. You clicked the Eclipse.exe file and this message was displayed: "A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must be available in order to run Eclipse. No Java Virtual Machine was found after sending the following locations: c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\javaw.exe" or something like this. Now I'm not saying that this solution will work for everyone but note that this is a good baseline starting point to find out your solution.

--- or ---

2b. In DOS, you typed Java or java -version in the command line, pressed  then this error was thrown:

"Picked up_Java_options: 
-Xrunjvmhook -Xbootclasspath/a:C"\Program~2\hp\Quickt~1\bin\Java_S~1\classes;c:\Progra~2\hp\Quickt~1\bin\Java_S~1\classes\jasmine.jar

Error occurred during initialization fo VM could not find agent library JVMhook on the library path; with error" Can't find dependent libraries..."

---

* Again, keep in mind, this process is being done with the FireFox v22 64-bit browser**** If using this browser, you need to check the following, to see if Java is enabled in the browser. I know what you're thinking but just do it!

1. Open or maximize the Firefox browser.
2. At the top left of the page, click Tools then the Add-ons option.
3. Click the Plugins option in the left pane.
4. You should see:

   Java Development Toolkit 7.0.250.17 10.25.2.17 NPRuntime Script Plug-in Library for
   Java (TM) Deploy. (or a plugin with a relevant version number)
5. Look to the right and make sure this plugin is Enabled~! If it is not Enabled, enable it!
6. If you do not see this plugin, at the top of this page, enter "Java" in the Search All Add-ons field, locate the plugin then install it.

---

1. Now go to Java.com and download the current version of Java for 64-bit. You need a JRE (Java Runtime Environment) and a JDK (Java Development Kit files and both have to be 64-bit!!!!!!! Once downloaded run both. They usually sit at either of these locations with these path distinctions:

c:\Program Files\Java\jre7   (This is the location of the JRE=Java Runtime Environment)
c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25  (This is the location of the JDK=Java Development Kit)

--- or ---

c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7  (This is the location of the JRE=Java Runtime Environment) 
c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25 (This is the location of the JDK=Java Development Kit)

*** Now keep in the these version numbers will change but here are the preferred locations.

---

1. Environment Variables Edits
2. Click Windows Start button (bottom left on Windows 7) then click Computer.
3. At the upper left, click System Properties. The Control Panel Home window opens.
4. Click the Advanced System Settings option.
5. Your User Account Control window may open.
6. Click the [Yes] button.
7. The Systems Properties window opens.
8. Click the [Environment Variables] button.
9. Go to the User Variables for (Your System Name here).
10. Delete everything here accept, the following:

    - PATH
    - TEMP
    - TMP
11. Now highlight the PATH variable and then click the [Edit] button.
12. The Edit User Variable window opens.
13. You want to add the following:

    ;c:\users\Your User Name\desktop\eclipse\eclipse\jre\bin;c:\Program Files (x86)\Java
     \jre\bin;c:\Program Files (x86)\jre7\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin
14. Click the [OK] button and the Edit User Variable window closes.
15. Now go to the System Variables section.
16. Delete all the Variables accept the following:

    - asl.log
    - CLASSPATH
    - Comspec
    - FP_NO_HOST_C...
    - NUMBER_Of_P...
    - OnlineServices
    - OD
    - PATH
    - PATHTEXT
    - PCBRANDS
    - Platform
    - PROCESSOR_A...
    - PROCESSOR_id...
    - PROCESSOR_LE...
    - PROCESSOR_R...
    - PSModulePath
    - TEMP
    - TERM
    - TMP
    - USERNAME
17. Click the [New...] button.
18. The New System Variable window opens.
19. In the Variable Name field (which the cursor is currently blinking in...), enter JAVA_HOME.
20. Then go to the Variable Value field and enter c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin;%JAVA_HOME%/bin.(Without the period, of course!)
21. Click the [OK] button and the New System Variable window closes.
22. Now highlight the PATH option and click the [Edit...] button.
23. The Edit System Variable window opens.
24. Go to the Variable value field and add the following at the end of the string already there:

    ;c:\Users\Your username here\desktop\eclipse\eclipse\jre\bin;c:\Program Files 
    (x86)\Java\jre7\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Java \jdk1.7.0_25\bin
25. Click the [OK] button and the Edit System Variable window closes.
26. Click the [OK] button to close the Environment Variables window.
27. Click the [OK] button to close the System Properties window.

---

1. Now for the Pista Resistance!!!!!!! Go back to the Eclipse folder on your desktop (or alternative location), then click open. Now download Notepad ++ from http://notepad-plus-plus.com and install it.
2. Use Notepad ++ to open the eclipse.ini file from the Eclipse folder. Using Notepad ++ keeps the eclipse.ini file's format correct.
3. With the eclipse.ini file opened with Notepad ++, look for -- launcher.append Vmargs. Once you've found this entry, place the cursor after it and then press . You should now see a space.
4. In that space enter the following: (and this must be entered exactly like what's listed below)

   -vm
   c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\
   c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin
5. Now click File then Save as, with the file name as Eclipse.ini, then click the [Save] button.
6. A message box will display asking "Do you want to replace the file?", click the [Yes] button.
7. Now click File then Exit and Notepad ++ closes.

---

1. Now close then restart the Firefox browser.

---

1. Now close then reopen the Eclipse folder. ( I know what you're thinking but just listen and nod and do it.)
2. Click the Eclipse.exe file and now you should see the Eclipse splash screen.
3. After a few seconds, a message displays asking you to select an Eclipse Workspace. You should have this Workspace on your desktop

or some where you can make this connection.

1. Now Eclipse is working! Let me know if this process worked for you!